# audio weird "tick sound" at track end

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

i created an app which plays a playlist of small tracks every thing was working fine , till windows phone 8.1 update

the problem is -> there is weird tick sound" at track end
so i tried to play the track in xbox music player it also has the same tick ...  i tried to play the audio at my pc and android device the audio is okay, so i think it's a wp8.1 issue or a comparability issue with my mp3 tracks

so, is there any specifications for the mp3 to be compatible with wp8.1?
or any work around in code, i was thinking a bout muting the sound before the track end , by the way i'm using AudioPlayerAgent

Comment: This is a known issue with WP8.1. I have this problem at the end of a track ([it used to be much worse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIZzIuPaEZY)). AFAIK there's no known fix. I'm hoping it will be fixed in WP10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All audio rendering processes encounter this same challenge/problem.  Root cause :  sound is a curve and as it varies above/below centerline, (typically varies from -1 to 0 to +1 where centerline is 0), if it ends not close enough to the centerline this pop/tick sound happens, (speaker is left in the lurge not at 0 and will physically instantaneously return to 0 producing the tick).  Solution : either the player ~helps~ the sound by artificially forcing the hand by ending the clip at the centerline or do similar as a preprocess step in the source media. This ending transition can happen quickly, yet not instantaneously, or you'd be back where you started with the instantaneous transition to 0.  Silence is just when the media supplies a series of zeros (IE. at centerline).

Comment: thanks for explanations, any suggestions for a tool or a code for pre-process the files   on the server